# Make `return` key more powerful

Tags: indentation, line-break, newlines

Normally `return` key is just `newline`, I believe a lot of people bind it to `newline-and-indent`, but `return` is relatively common used key, the `C-u RET` and `C-- RET` basically do nothing but same as `return`, I don't want to waste prefix features. How can I make it do these?

1. If I type `return`, it will do normal things(e.g., it will create a new line and indent if I type `return` at the end of a line; it will split the line from here, create new line, jump to it and then indent if I type `return` in the middle of the line.)
2. If I type `C-u return`(whether in the middle or at the end of the line), it will create a new line(not split), jump to it but not indent.(like `C-e C-o C-n`)
3. If I type `C-- return`(whether in the middle or at the end of the line), it will create a new line above the current line and jump to it.(like `C-a C-o`)

I already made these happen using `global-set-key`, but wasted `S-return` and `M-S-return`, if anyone can advance the default `return` key using prefix argument feature, that would be better.

Update: 
I got the following `defun`, but it doesn't work, what's wrong with it?

```
(defun advanced-return (&optional arg)
  (interactive "p")
  (if (equal arg '-)
      (progn
        (beginning-of-line)
        (open-line))
    (if (equal arg '(4))
        (progn
          (end-of-line)
          (open-line)
          (next-line))
      (newline-and-indent))))
```

If you can make it work, is it possible not to `defun` a new function, but just put them inside

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<return>")
...
)
```

Comment: If you don't know much elisp yet, this looks like an achievable project. To get started, look up interactive prefixes, cond, eolp, and bolp.

Comment: Just define a new command (instead of putting a lambda form in `global-set-key`) that does what you want, and bind it to `(kbd "RET")`.

Comment: I just have no idea how to use both `C-u` and `C--` at the same time.

Comment: @CodyChan with C-u, the prefix argument is '(4). With C--, it is `-1`. Just check for its value.

Comment: Be sure to read `C-h i g` `(elisp) Prefix Command Arguments` `RET`

Comment: @phils I did hours ago, execute me, I still got no clue.

Comment: You also need to check `C-h f` `interactive`. I can see that you're using "p" when you want upper-case "P" to get the raw argument rather than a number.

Comment: @phils Trust me, I did check `interactive`, sometimes giving someone a fish is the best solution, I just need an example. Besides this comments list is really long now.

Comment: Everything you need to know about testing and using different prefix arguments is contained `C-h v current-prefix-arg` and `C-h f prefix-numeric-value`. And you can check `C-h f interactive` too. If that's not enough, then read [**(elisp)`Prefix Command Arguments`**](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Prefix-Command-Arguments.html). And above all, *try some code*. ***Lisp is interactive*** - it is simple and immediate to try things out.

Comment: I thought about having a vim-lime ```open-line``` that does not split. Did you achieve your goal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- You need `(interactive "P")` (not `"p"`) to get a raw prefix argument (i.e. the ability to distinguish between `C-u` and `C-u 4`). See `C-h f` `interactive`.
- The raw prefix argument for `C--` is not `(-1)`, but `-`. See `C-h i g` `(elisp) Prefix Command Arguments`.
- `open-line` takes a required argument.

```
(defun advanced-return (&optional arg)
  (interactive "P")
  (if (equal arg '-) ;; C--
      (progn
        (beginning-of-line)
        (open-line 1))
    (if (equal arg '(4)) ;; C-u
        (progn
          (end-of-line)
          (open-line 1)
          (next-line))
      (newline-and-indent))))
```

- You might also write this as a `cond` expression, rather than a series of nested `if`s. That would be structurally cleaner (although I always think the (lack of) indentation is a problem for readability with `cond`, so YMMV).

```
(defun advanced-return (&optional arg)
  (interactive "P")
  (cond ((equal arg '-) ;; C--
         (beginning-of-line)
         (open-line 1))
        ((equal arg '(4)) ;; C-u
         (end-of-line)
         (open-line 1)
         (next-line))
        (t ;; Otherwise
         (newline-and-indent))))
```

Comment: It there any chance that I can put them into `(global-set-key (kbd "<return>")...`(not `defun` a new `advanced-return`????

Comment: Yes, with a lambda expression, but you don't want that. It messes with the documentation -- `C-h k RET` would show you the entire function definition -- unformatted, and maybe as byte-code -- instead of a name.

Comment: I confirm this works in GNU Emacs 24.3.1